# how to insert data in my databse using entitymanger?

Tags: java, jpa

please please can you help me

I have  two Entitys Student and Adress releted by @OneToOne relationship

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int idstudent;
   private String firstname;
   private String name;
   @OneToOne
   private Adress adress;
   //setters and getters
}

public class Adress implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idadress;
    private String street;
    private String codezip;
    @OneToOne
    private Student student;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I want to insert data using entity manger I try that by it dosn't work

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "JPADD")
EntityManager em;
Student student = new Student();
student.setfirstname("cc");
student.setname("cc");
Adress adress = new Adress();
adress.setstreet("ccccccccc");
adress.setstudent(student);
em.persist(adress)
em.persist(student);
```

help me pleaaaaaaaaase :)

Comment: the code I have posted works well when I delete     adress.setstudent(student)

Comment: the probleme is not that it doesn't instantiate an EntityManger

Comment: Wasn't paying attention to the annotation, [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader or Crystal Ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/172496) still applies.

Comment: What exception do you get, if any? Your EntityManager doesn't get instantiated? Please provide more information like technologies you're using, server, providers, etc.

Comment: Please provide more information. Maybe your persistence.xml, but minimally what it is that doesn't work. Is an Exception being thrown, does nothing at all get saved into the db, does too much get saved in the DB. Does the right amount get saved in the db but the wrong data. ... and so on. Are you aware you've created two unidirectional relationships and not a birdectional? Does the PersistenceUnit create the tables. ... and so on. Basically: Give us a lot more

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to guess what's your problem :

You're trying to persist an Address, which has a Student field.

Now, seems like you have no Cascade attributes on your mapping so, maybe, the problem is that you're trying to persist an Address which has a Student that's not in your DB.

Try swapping the last two lines in order to persiste the Student before the Address.

You may also consider changing

```
@OneToOne
private Student student;
```

to

```
@OneToOne(cascadeType = Cascade.PERSIST)
private Student student;
```

Keep in mind that I'm just trying to guess because I don't have enough details to help you!